# Which is better approach, 2 stored procedure calls or one big call and just filter the list?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, stored-procedures

This is more of a performance question rather than code.

So in our requirement, we would need to check a person in the database with a specified ssn under a specific "administrator". We also would need to check if that person's spouse is also under the same administrator.

We've a stored procedure which retrieves all the persons under the specified administrator.

In our C# code, we have a list of, say, appointments. Each object holds the data for the person's and spouse's ssn as well as the administrator id.

```
foreach(var obj in myList) {
    Guid adminID = obj.Admin;
    string spouseSSN = obj.SpouseSSN,
      iSSN = obj.PersonSSn;

    List < Person > adminSub = RetrievePersonsUnderAdmin(adminID); //calls the sp

    Person spouse = adminSub.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SSN == spouseSSN);
    Person iPerson = adminSub.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SSN == iSSN);
}
```

That's the previous implementation. Now we wanted to modify the sp so we can fetch the person right away using ssn. What I did was made it accept an optional `@OptionalCondition nvarchar(max)` parameter which will be added to the `WHERE` clause:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @query nvarchar(max)
        SET @query = 
            'SELECT
                . . . . -- select columns
            WHERE
                . . . . -- where clause
            ' + ISNULL(@CustomCondition, '') -- additional conditions @CustomCondition, optional
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query
END
```

This way, we could use it in our C# code to do this:

```
Person spouse = RetrievePersonsUnderAdmin(adminID, string.Format("AND p.SSN = '{0}'", spouseSSN)).FirstOrDefault();

Person spouse = RetrievePersonsUnderAdmin(adminID, string.Format("AND p.SSN = '{0}'", iSSN )).FirstOrDefault();
```

Question is, which is better, calling 2 sps or the previous implementation? Note that an admin can have 500 - 1000 subordinates.

**EDIT:**

> If you guys may, you could post your answers here while also including all flaws you observed in my code. This way, future devs might stumble upon the same questions I had and hopefully this post could help them. Thanks for the guys in the comment section for the help.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Please explain why you are using *stored procedures* to run queries.  There are good reasons why, but it is non-standard.  I would recommend that you start with queries or views.

Comment: Your current approach is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @GordonLinoff, we are doing some other things in the sp, it's not just a simple `SELECT`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes, but it wont be because that functionality is done by a background job which is on the server. There is no whatsoever UI which leads to that functionality. But yeah, I agree that it would be vulnerable for sql injection, if there is a way the outside world has access to that.

Comment: @GeomanYabes: Are you 100% sure that this SP will never ever be used from somewhere else and that the code there will never change? If you can guarantee that or you don't care it's fine.

Comment: Yep, currently.

Comment: Fetching only the data you need from the database certainly seems preferable over fetching all possible data and then filtering it later.  The approach you've taken to do so, however, is... flawed.  Aside from the aforementioned SQL injection that you're just sort of hand-waving as not being a problem, it's also potentially short circuiting the database engine's ability to cache query plans (since you're worried about performance and whatnot), and it's also just a bit of a mess. Why not just... query the data? If this *must* be in a stored procedure, create a stored procedure for this purpose.

Comment: @David, so you mean, the last one?

Comment: @GeomanYabes: The last *what*?  It's not clear what you're asking in your last comment.

Comment: I mean, calling 2 sps instead of one bulk then filter.

Comment: @GeomanYabes: Or calling one stored procedure which does specifically and only what you need.  I'm definitely *not* recommending using the stored procedure calls you've indicated in the question.  Creating a single "God function" which does anything you tell it to is generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: I would think for smaller data sets, filtering in the application layer or in the database layer would not really play such a huge role in the subject of performance. If it was to be thought through, since dynamic query's condition can change, I doubt that the SQL server is going to cache a plan that will be used often for that, therefore, I am not even sure if it would be beneficial.

Comment: I think passing a chunk of SQL into your database to be concatenated in a proc to a larger sql statement is just bad practice regardless of faster/better questions. You want to avoid dynamically swapping fields and tables. To do otherwise opens you up to SQL Injection and performance issues. Writing fresh logic to fetch data for a person based on SSN instead of trying to shoe-horn it into an existing proc would be better. You'll get better performance, easier to test and debug code, and keep from opening a big security hole.

Comment: Also, if your proc is so complex that shoe-horning more features into it is preferable to creating a second proc to handle this "search by ssn" feature, then you should consider refactoring before moving forward with adding new features. But that's me making a lot of assumptions here based on how it appears your application is designed. So grain of salt...